# Concepts of IoTHub data on Event Hub

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, iot

I am new to IoTHub.I have a basic query on how the data is to be ... when sent to IoTHub\EventHub.
From my reading I see both -  `IoT Hub and Event Hub` - as different entities.

**My Requirement**

1. I need to develop an app that would send data from Raspberry Pi3 device to IoT Hub
2. Another Web App to subscribe this telemetry data and display(push) on Graph showing real time data (and temperature display ...) ===> A Dashboard to display data.

**My Query**

What should I be using   `IoT Hub or Event Hub` to publish\subscribe my data?

**What I have tried**

I have created a sample console app to send\receive data to IoT Hub (specifying IoT Hub url\connection string\device key ...) ===> It worked fine.

When I tried to receive the data from IoT Hub to display on a Graph in an Web App I couldn't get it done and take it forward. 
So I moved on to `EventHub` 
 *(Or do we have any possibility here from IotHub to achieve my goal?)*

===> created a sample Console App to send Data to Event Hub(with event hub connection string,storage key ...)

===> created a Web App (employed WebSocket\SignalR) to subscribe the data from EventHub partition and push to UI to draft the graph.

===> This works fine.

===> But I need to send data to Event Hub from my device Raspberry Pi 3 developing app in UWP. Here I get stuck as in UWP there is no support for  Azure Service Bus. Tried AMPQNetLite dll too; but have not yet succeeded as some or the other issue blocks.

**Next Steps**

Kindly give me your suggestion and pointers on what is the right step next to implement a solution for my requirement.

Comment: What kind of Web App? Can you receive the data from IoT Hub in the app?

Comment: I created an ASP.Net MVC app to get the data from IoT Hub. Using the IoTHub connection I was able to receive the data in app using(inside) the while loop. But my goal is to get the latest data from IoT Hub and display immediately on Graph. Do you have any pointers\sample to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

If your only requirement is to send data in one way from the device to the cloud, Event Hubs can do the job very well. IoT Hubs are built on top of Event Hubs and offer additional functionality like cloud-to-device messages.

The older Service Bus SDK is indeed incompatible with Universal App Platform as you noticed. But we have a newer library now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send.

Using the `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` package on the device end you should be able to send messages to the Event Hub.

Comment: My initial task is to only send data from device to cloud. But later we would need to extend the functionality to send back data to device from cloud. In that case should I go with IoT Hub using IoTHub connection string to send data to IoT Hub? If so can you please show me some pointers\sample on how to get the data from IoTHub on Web Application. All samples on googling seems to be a ConsoleApp.